# Replacing numpy element that are not finite

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with non finite elements. For example :

```
myMax = np.finfo(float).max
myArray = np.array((0,1,myMax*2))
```

I would like to replace non finite element with `myMax`.

The following instruction does not work :

```
myArray[not np.isfinite(myArray)]=myMax
```

So, I use this command :

```
myArray=[i if np.isfinite(i) else myMax for i in myArray]
```

Is it the correct way to do that or is there a better solution in term of performance (execution time and/or memory use) ?

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the bitwise NOT (`~`):

```
myArray[~np.isfinite(myArray)] = myMax
```

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> myMax = np.finfo(float).max
>>> myArray = np.array((0,1,myMax*2))
<stdin>:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
>>> np.isfinite(myArray)
array([ True,  True, False])
>>> not np.isfinite(myArray)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>>> ~np.isfinite(myArray)
array([False, False,  True])
```